# Xamarin iOS MapKit Cannot display specific Image as Pin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, mapkit

I tried https://github.com/xamarin/ios-samples/tree/master/ios11/MapKitSample
to create a clustering Map.
In BikeView.cs, when I want to change the Pin with

```
Image = UIImage.FromBundle("Unicycle");
```

The default Pin is display above the one I want.

[image]

Do you have any idea to customize a pin?

Comment: Just remove `Image = UIImage.FromBundle("Unicycle");` line.

Comment: What ^^ said, you need to set the GlyphImage, not the Image property

Comment: GlyphImage put me my image inside the pin, I just want my image without the Apple pin

Comment: Any update or clue to help me?